# How to inject DbContext in ASP.NET Core API following clean architecture?

Tags: asp.net, clean-architecture

I have this structure for the context of `DbContext` dependency injection.

Domain project

- Entities

BusinessLogic project

- Feature

Infrastructure

- DbContext is here

API Project

- Controllers

Question is should the infrastructure project have reference to domain project to add the entities to `DbContext`? Can the infrastracture layer pass through 1 layer below to access domain layer?

Comment: The Api project has also a reference to the Domain project and it is deeper than Infrastructure

Comment: @SirRufo Does it break the clean architecture? Or there can be exceptions?

Comment: This seems like a suitable question to ask on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the eShop Reference Application repo : [eShop GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/tree/main/src)

At the Ordering service you can see how they deal with the infrastructure dependency!
[image: Ordering projects image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very philosophical question, I think that the infrastructure layer can depend on the domain layer, but not vice versa (in a pure architecture, logic should not depend on the infrastructure).

But I would also add that it is possible to duplicate entities for the infrastructure layer, because If this is not done, then domain models may have infrastructure attributes (or something else).
But you need to look at the situation, sometimes adding extra entities is an overhead

IMHO